# Jupyter Autocomplete Only Works in Cell with Import

Tags: python, autocomplete, jupyter-notebook

As title says, autocomplete in Jupyter only works in same cell that package was imported.

This question has been asked but i didn't see a working answer for me.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

plt. (pressing tab gives choices, but if plt. is in different cell, it doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you didn't run cell with `import`.

First execute cell with importing libraries and then try to autocomplete in another cell.